# Nginx proxy_pass location absolute paths

Tags: nginx, path, absolute, proxypass

I had a proxied page: `http://destsrv:8089/index.html`
It contains link to absolute path like: `href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

And nginx is configured like:

```
 location /admin/ {
              proxy_pass http://destsrv:8089/;
        }
```

Although when accessing the `http://myproxy/admin/index.html`
it is trying to get .css from:
`http://myproxy/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

But expected is:
`http://myproxy/admin/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
location /admin/ {
   proxy_pass http://destsrv:8089/;
   sub_filter_once off;
   sub_filter "http://destsrv:8089/" "$scheme://$host/admin";
   sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/admin/';
   sub_filter "href='/" "href='/admin/";
}
```

You basically want to fix the urls using filters

Comment: what about href="//sth" type of links? Is it possible to set rule which do not touch them when replacing href="/sth" at the same time?

Comment: Try this `sub_filter '<head>' '<head>\n<base href="/deluge/">';`. Remove the other href ones

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. That's why the app being proxied, if it can be run on a base url then its the best.

Comment: yes, that's better but wil not work when having other then 'href=' links eg. 'src=' or 'action=' :) Tried also this: one: sub_filter '"base": "/"' '"base": "/deluge/"';
And i had found the other problem which I cannot diagnose for now. When using angular .js for form validation. Seems that sth is wrong when proxy on different location (eg. admin) than root (/) and using subfilters.

Comment: my GOOD i search this for 23412312 days :D Thanks so much. Now i can bypass CORS damm thing on my project